# Netbeans and Codeigniter Applications

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I'm still trying to figure out how to work with netbeans and codeigniter projects. I have the following structure tree and I am trying to figure out tht when I open up `http://localhost/MyFirstProject` that it'll use the index.php file that resides in the site folder. Anybody use netbeans here and can tell me. I've already started the project.

```
Projects
- MyFirstProject
    - Source Files
        - application
        - site
            - assets
            index.php
        - system
    - Test Files
    - Important Files
    - Include Path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a bit of a non-standard layout, but you can change the index.php file like this:

1. In the project explorer, right click on your project MyFirstProject
2. Select Properties
3. Select the 'Run Configuration' category
4. Modify the 'Index File' field to point to site/index.php (you can use the browse button to select it)

Enjoy :-)